# Difference between & and = for passing functions to isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

`&` is always described as the way to call a function on the parent scope inside a directive's isolated scope.

However, since `=` creates two-way binding and a function is just another value, shouldn't it be just as effective for this purpose?

The only difference I see is that using &, you can modify the passed function without affecting the parent, since it's one-way binding.

So why is `&` usually recommended over `=` for this use case?

There is also some weird behavior that I've come across. Using `&` gives you a function wrapper. If you unwrap it in the controller and call it, it will resolve differently than if you unwrap it as the result of an ng-click inside the directive.

I've set up an experiment in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvzEk/33/):

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="parentFunc1()(1); parentFunc2(1)">Directive</button>', 
        scope: {
           parentFunc1: '&func1',
           parentFunc2: '=func2',
        },
        controller: Ctrl2,
    }
});

function Ctrl2($scope) {
    //Step 1
    console.log($scope.parentFunc1);
    $scope.parentFunc1()(1);
    $scope.parentFunc2(1);

    //Step 2
    $scope.oldParent1 = $scope.parentFunc1;
    $scope.parentFunc1 = function (value) {
        console.log(value+1);
    };
    $scope.parentFunc1(1);
    $scope.parentFunc2(1);

    //Step 3    
    $scope.parentFunc1 = $scope.oldParent1;
    $scope.parentFunc2 = function (value) {
        console.log(value+2);
    };
    console.log($scope.parentFunc1);
    $scope.parentFunc1()(1);
    $scope.parentFunc2(1);

    //Step 4 -> Click the directive button
}

function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.foo = function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    };
}
```

This logs "1,1; 2,1; 1,2; 2,2". The last two pairs of values leave me puzzled because they seem to execute the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question!

See the difference between `&` and `=` is simple.

When you are declaring a directive scope, and you add to it `&` it means that you are declaring a **function** within the scope rather if it was `=` it was for a **regular property**.

> **WAIT WAIT, those two examples above just worked and they are both functions!**

Well that's true but hold on,

You just used them incorrectly.
Using the `:"&func"` means that you are adding a function that will be **evaluated soon.**

Confused?

I'll  type a perfect example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
.directive("scopeDemo", function (){
 return {
  template: "<div><p>Name: {{local}}, City: {{cityFn()}}</p></div>",
  scope:{
       local: "=nameprop",
       cityFn: "&city"
       }
    }
  }
}).controller("scopeCtrl, function($scope){
     $scope.data = {
        name: "Shahar",
        defaultCity: "London"
     };

     $scope.getCity = function(name){
        return name == 'Shahar' ? $scope.data.defaultCity : "unknown";
     }
});
</script>
<body ng-controller="scopeCtrl">
   <div>
     Direct Binding: <input ng-model="data.name" />
    </div>
   <div scope-demo city="getCity(data.name)" nameprop="data.name"></div> //Reference 1.
</body>
```

As you can see I've written two attributes to my scope's directive.
one accepts a PROPERTY and one accepts a FUNCTION.
As you can see the result of this directive is rather dull, but it explains the whole point.

You will not succeed doing so if you try to make a function with the '=' since Angular will just ignore that.

I hope it clears it up.

Good luck!

Comment: Your example is incomplete, but from what I see, you're just working within the pattern that most common examples give. I'm not using anything 'incorrectly', moreso I'm trying something that goes against this common pattern and asking why this is the accepted way of doing things. First of all, `=` binds a variable, which means that variable can be a function. And if you use '&', it creates a function wrapper. Calling it on the parent like "getCity(data.name)" gives you a function inside the directive that you can then execute and lets you use the parent's parameter inside the directive.

Comment: But I could replicate that by passing the variable (=) or the wrapper (&) and then also passing in the variable I want to call the function with through another attribute on the directive.

Comment: Thanks for uploading that Fiddle, it looks like you haven't tested things before responding. All three methods return to log London, Does all three methods available to evaluate expression to their binding? take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/dh4gk2sL/1/ change cityFn to 1 or 2 or 3 and look for the result yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `&` and `=` binding strategies takes place when you want to call function on parent scope with parameters also passed from parent scope.

Let's say you have following controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function() {
  $scope.mans = [{name: 'Peter'}, {name: 'Alex'}]

  $scope.someMethod = function(par) {
     console.log(par);
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="man in mans">
    <button my-dir="someMethod(man.name)">Click me</button>
</div>
```

In this case `myDir` directive should only use `&` binding strategy, because the directive knows nothing aboout passed parameters.